# Is init_priority supported in clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++

`init_priority` is well defined in [GCC's attribute doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html), so the code could use the attribute to control the initialization order of glocal/static variables.

In clang, I see similar test code as well, e.g. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/test/SemaCXX/init-priority-attr.cpp has code like

```
Two foo __attribute__((init_priority(101))) ( 5, 6 );
```

But I do not find any `init_priority` in [clang's attribute documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html).

So the questions are:

1. Is `init_priority` officially supported in clang?
2. If yes, does it mean the documentation is missing `init_priority` stuff?

Answer (score 1):

> Is init_priority officially supported in clang?

Yes, this attribute is supported in clang compiler.

> If yes, does it mean the documentation is missing init_priority stuff?

This is also correct. They missed to document this property. (Ref: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/802485f170af8d8965817bf0dc3f1336625f3adb/include/clang/Basic/Attr.td#L1922-L1927)

Comment: Please re-format the answer (which has duplicated texts), and the link seems not pointing to the init_priority attribute, you probably need to use a permanent link instead, e.g. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/802485f170af8d8965817bf0dc3f1336625f3adb/include/clang/Basic/Attr.td#L1922-L1927
After that I will accept the answer. Thanks!